# ASP.NET MVC Mapping Route Config Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I realize there are plenty of questions like this on SO but none of the solutions seem to work for me, which is probably because I'm missing something simple that I don't know of. In my application, I added a controller called **ErrorController** with a view called **Error.cshtml**. The controller looks like this:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string errorMessage)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = errorMessage;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now let's say I want to redirect to this action from a different controller. I was able to achieve that using

```
public ActionResult DoStuff(MyModel model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("", "Error", new { errorMessage = "SomeError" });
}
```

When redirect is called, I notice that the parameter is being passed as a query string:

```
/Error?errorMessage=SomeError
```

I would like to be able to pass the parameter as a route value, so my URL looks like

```
/Error/SomeError
```

So I added the following mapping to my RouteConfig.cs file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Test",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{errorMessage}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", errorMessage = "defaultErrorMessageTest" }
);
```

But it doesn't work. When I try to invoke the method with a URL like `/Error/HelloWorld` I get a yellow-screen error that says the resource cannot be found. Am I missing something here?

Comment: try filling in the controller name:  return RedirectToAction("Error", "Index", new { errorMessage = "SomeError" });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
return RedirectToAction("", "Error", new { errorMessage = "SomeError" });
```

to

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { errorMessage = "SomeError" });
```

And then change your route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test",
    url: "error/{errorMessage}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", errorMessage = "defaultErrorMessageTest" }
);
```

Also, make sure this route comes **above** your default route.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem in RouteConfig, this works fine for me.

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Test",
            url: "Error/{errorMessage}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", errorMessage = "defaultErrorMessageTest" }
          );


        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Defualt",
           url: "{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "DoStuff" }
         );           
    }
}
 public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string errorMessage)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = errorMessage;
        return View("Error");
    }     
}
 public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DoStuff()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { errorMessage = "SomeError" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i understand what you mean. I've upadated my answer, i think it's your situation.

Comment: I think problem in return View(), you should  return View("Error"). I fix it in  my  answer code.